# Numpy Array get datatype by cell?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a single numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([1, "sd", 3.6])
```

I want to detect the cells with string type values.

This:

```
res = arr == type(str)
```

returns all false.

Any help?

Comment: you can see the dtype of an array using `dtype` method: `arr.dtype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, "sd", 3.6])
```

You'll notice that the values in this array are not numerics and strings, they're just strings.

```
>>> arr
array(['1', 'sd', '3.6'], dtype='<U32')
```

You'll also note that they're not python strings. There is a reason for this but it isn't important here.

```
>>> type(arr[1])
<class 'numpy.str_'>

>>> type(arr[1]) == type(str)
False
```

You should not try to mix data types like you are doing. Use a list instead. The difference in data types that you have in your input list is lost when you turn it into an array. I note that you're calling an array element a 'cell' - it isn't, arrays don't work like spreadsheets.

That said, if you absolutely must do this:

```
arr = np.array([1, "sd", 3.6], dtype=object)

>>> arr
array([1, 'sd', 3.6], dtype=object)
```

This will keep all the array elements as python objects instead of using numpy dtypes.

```
>>> np.array([type(x) == str for x in arr])
array([False,  True, False])
```

Then you can test the type of each element accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You better to do it before doing the conversion from list like this since otherwise all the array elements are changed to same data type (for example `str` here)

```
arr = [1, "sd", 3.6]
[type(x)for x in arr]
```

Output:

```
[int, str, float]
```